# Merkle tree-based PoR

Tags: secure-storage, coding-theory, remote-data-checking

As you may already know, proofs of retrievability (PoR) can be constructed using MACs, Signatures (as stated [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/073.pdf)) or Merkle tree (like [this](https://www.arijuels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/JK07.pdf)).

The PoRs that are based on MACs or signatures usually use the notion of extractability. Informally, it states that if a prover can convince the verifier (with a high probability), then the prover must know the file. So there exists an extractor that can interact with the prover and after a polynomial number of iterations, it can extract the full file.

However, I have not seen any Merkle tree-based PoR that uses any notion of extractability.

**Question**: Can Merkle tree-based PoRs also support extractability too?